# Is it well defined to use a function pointer that's been cast to another type in a comparison?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

Function pointers of dissimilar types can't be directly compared :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 0; }
void bar(int) {}

int main()
{
    // Doesn't compile, the comparison is not allowed
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (&foo == &bar) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, if one function pointer is cast to the type of the other function pointer, is it defined behavior to compare the result of that cast with the other function pointer?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 0; }
void bar(int) {}

int main()
{
    auto cast_ptr = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&bar)>(&foo);

    // Printed "false" when I tried it, but is this guaranteed?
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (cast_ptr == &bar) << std::endl;
}
```

How about if both operators have been cast to a common but different type?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 0; }
void bar(int) {}

int main()
{
    using cast_type = void(*)();
    auto cast_foo = reinterpret_cast<cast_type>(&foo);
    auto cast_bar = reinterpret_cast<cast_type>(&bar);

    // Also printed "false" when I tried it, but is this guaranteed?
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (cast_foo == cast_bar) << std::endl;
}
```

I understand that function pointers compare equal if and only if they both point to `nullptr` or to the same function. What's not clear to me is rather or not using a function pointer that's been cast to another function pointer type in a comparison is allowed.

**Context**

I'm maintaining a c++ library with a c compatible API. The library logs every call made to API functions. It's become useful to selectively disable this logging for certain functions at run time. The best current proposal in terms of usability is to supply a new API function which takes as an argument a pointer to the API function whose logging should be suppressed. Since the API functions have different arguments, these pointers would have different types and would need to be cast to a common function pointer type such as `void(*)()`. Then, before logging an API function call, a container of `void(*)()` would be searched for the address of the called function to know rather or not to log that call.

Comment: How about casting to `std::intptr_t`?

Comment: @PasserBy That's an interesting idea. `std::intptr_t` can store a pointer, but it's not clear to me that it can store a function pointer. Function pointers are not required to have the same size as regular pointers.

Comment: _A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined._ Seems like its good to go (mostly) if the size is large enough.

Comment: _Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified._ Seems like casting to different function pointer types and using them is unreliable

Comment: instead of relying on implementation defined behaviour, can't you just store type-erased wrappers with properly defined operator== ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yes, and I have successfully implemented such a system. However note from the context section that this system has to work through a c compatible API. I can't see a way for the user to provide the concrete function pointer type. I can't use templates and can't use `std::type_info`.

Comment: @PasserBy Is there a guarantee that a the integer representation of a function pointer unique and distinct from any other, including the integer representation for function pointers of other types?

Comment: All I see is it's implementation-defined, better than unspecified anyways

Comment: Another way is converting to an object pointer, but it is no better. _Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined_

Answer (score 0):

From [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast)

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. [...] Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

It is unspecified whether casted function pointers compare equally.

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined.

Hence it is a natural choice to convert to `std::intptr_t` or some other suitable type, provided the implementation doesn't use some wacky conversion.

From [GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation)

> A cast from pointer to integer discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is larger than the integer type, sign-extends<sup>1</sup> if the pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, otherwise the bits are unchanged.

AKA the sane conversion. Which is probably what you'll find in most cases I'd bet.

<sub>[1] Future versions of GCC may zero-extend, or use a target-defined ptr_extend pattern. Do not rely on sign extension.</sub>

Comment: As mentioned in the question's comments, I'm not convinced that `std::intptr_t` can store a function pointer, whose size is not required to be the same as a regular pointer. I'm also not certain that the resulting integer representation will be unique to the function pointer with regard to the integer representation for function pointers of other types. I do appreciate your time and the research you've done. I'll see if I can't find anything to address these new concerns.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's the best I got out of gcc's documentation. There are no other conversions allowed on a function pointer AFAIK, so this is probably what you've got. In this case, I'd probably just trust the implementation not to screw me over. You _know_ no sane implementation will have two different functions with the same address, and since gcc said the bits are unchanged, I'd say that it's a guarantee on uniqueness.

Comment: If OP wanted to keep in a more C-esque sense, would `void *` cast of function address's suffice. Then for comparison typecast them (depending on architecture) to a `uint32_t` or a `uint64_t` suffice and compare their addresses like so?